how to add values from two panda rows without using for loop
I have a panda dataframe which looks like follows.
name  name2   date      value     buy_price     sell_price
a       1    2-2-24     100          1              3
f       2    2-2-24     100          2              4     
d       1    3-3-24     200          9              2
b       2    3-3-24     200          5              7
e       1    4-3-24     300          2              1
d       2    4-3-24     300          5              6

i want 2 rows with common date and value and then add buy_price of 1 and sell_price of 2.
i can do this using multiple for loops. but the database is huge and i want to find a way to make it fast if possible. is there any way to do it?
expected answer =
1+4
9+7
2+6


Do you want to group by date or by position?

For common date and value per name2 create MultiIndex first and then select by 1 and 2 with sum MultiIndex Series with Series.add:
df1 = df.set_index(['name2','date','value'])
    
out = df1.loc[1,'buy_price'].add(df1.loc[2,'sell_price']).reset_index(name='sum')
print (out)
     date  value  sum
0  2-2-24    100    5
1  3-3-24    200   16
2  4-3-24    300    8

How it working:
print (df.set_index(['name2','date','value']))
                   name  buy_price  sell_price
name2 date   value                            
1     2-2-24 100      a          1           3
2     2-2-24 100      f          2           4
1     3-3-24 200      d          9           2
2     3-3-24 200      b          5           7
1     4-3-24 300      e          2           1
2     4-3-24 300      d          5           6

print (df1.loc[1,'buy_price'])
date    value
2-2-24  100      1
3-3-24  200      9
4-3-24  300      2
Name: buy_price, dtype: int64

print (df1.loc[2,'sell_price'])
date    value
2-2-24  100      4
3-3-24  200      7
4-3-24  300      6
Name: sell_price, dtype: int64


this is not working. key error

@mona - then test print (df.columns.tolist()) if not same space like ' name2'

IIUC, set_index with name2 and date, then slice the respective columns (buy_price for name 1, sell_price for name 2) with loc, and finally add the two Series:
tmp = df.set_index(['name2', 'date'])

tmp.loc[1, 'buy_price'].add(tmp.loc[2, 'sell_price'])

Output:
date
2-2-24     5
3-3-24    16
4-3-24     8
dtype: int64

Another option would be to pivot your data:
tmp = df.pivot(index=['date', 'value'], columns='name2')
out = tmp[('buy_price', 1)].add(tmp[('sell_price', 2)]).reset_index(name='total')

Output:
     date  value  total
0  2-2-24    100      5
1  3-3-24    200     16
2  4-3-24    300      8

If speed is the most important and your data is always organized in pairs (1,2,1,2) of dates, you could also use numpy:
out = (df['buy_price'].to_numpy()[::2]
      +df['sell_price'].to_numpy()[1::2]
      )

Output: array([ 5, 16,  8])
As a Series:
out = pd.Series(df['buy_price'].to_numpy()[::2]
               +df['sell_price'].to_numpy()[1::2],
                df['date'].to_numpy()[::2])

Output:
2-2-24     5
3-3-24    16
4-3-24     8
dtype: int64


first part of you answer is correct. it is grouping the based on date and value. but you got the second part wrong may be i was little ambiguous there. after grouping it based on value and date i want to buy_price of name2(1) and sell_price of name2(2). name to has only 2 values

@mona do you mean you don't care about "value"? Then just use df.pivot(index='date', columns='name2')

@mona in the end, is your data always sorted by date and 1/2 order? If yes, then the numpy approach will be the fastest. I'll add an update if you need to also have the dates

i do care about the value. first i want to organize it based on date and value. then want to add based of name2

Then the set_index+loc approach is the safest, and numpy would be the fastest if you already know that the data is in the correct order

okay thanks. i will check it in some time
